# Copy/Paste ListPlot in MS Word as enhanced metafile

Tags: plotting, grid-lines, copy-as

I tried to copy/paste a `ListPlot` in MS Word document as an enhanced metafile.
I usually succeed in pasting `ListPlot`s -- see the picture on the right.

However, when I used `Gridlines` the pasted picture is blurred like on the left.

Any ideas how to fix that?

```
(* Blurred *)
ListPlot[{{10, 0.249}, {20, 0.481}, {40, 0.804}, {60, 1.346}}, GridLines -> {{{10, Dotted}, {20, Dotted}, {30, Dotted}, {40, 
  Dotted}, {50, Dotted}, {60, Dotted}}, {{0.5, Dotted}, {1, 
  Dotted}, {1.5, Dotted}}}]
(* Smooth *)
ListPlot[{{10, 0.249}, {20, 0.481}, {40, 0.804}, {60, 1.346}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in the Dotted style that doesn't translate well into EMF or other formats. I'd use a light dashing instead:

```
ListPlot[
 {{10, 0.249}, {20, 0.481}, {40, 0.804}, {60, 1.346}}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[10, 60, 10], Range[0.5, 1, 0.5]}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Dashed]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then right click, "Save Graphic As...", and select a file name and the EMF file format. You can then import or drag the resulting EMF file into Word. Here is a screenshot of what the above plot looks like in Word when I drag it in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your polite response, and I have succeeded that! But, the cause of blurred is not Dotted, it depends on whether "Range[]" is used in "Gridlines" or not.